# Style.Triggers & DataTrigger eliminate style?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I use Style.Triggers & DataTrigger to Enable/Disable a button.

But the style I've applied is gone. It is the Expression Dark.

**Is it possible to fix it and return style to the button?**

Thanks!!!

```
 <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Uid="ResourceDictionary_1"  >
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Uid="ResourceDictionary_3" Source="/Themes/ExpressionDark.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

[image]

---

**SOLUTION:**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}" >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Style try something like this:

```
<Button ....>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
           ....
       </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Sorry which "Style" do u mean? Where do I have to implement it?

Comment: @DmitryBoyko the style in your button (the only one shown in your question). Have updated to hopefully be clearer.

Comment: I did and I have the error: Error 5 Can only base on a Style with target type that is base type 'IFrameworkInputElement'.

Comment: I found the solution. It should be like: <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}" >  So u was almost near! Anyway to you +1, bro! :)

Comment: Cool, will add your bit to the answer for others.